# zoom, scale, pan etc in an application and printing

Tags: graphics

I have a C# windows application where I display photos for editing. The displayed
image is scaled to fit the screen. I allow pan, zoom, rotate, crop operations. Once
the editing is done, I would like to print. Now since the displayed image is scaled
before any of these operations, how can I print the photo correctly?

- one option is to do the operations on the original image and then scale it and display it.

Is it what is normally done?

Comment: Have you tried to implement the method you described?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with GameDev

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is load two copies of the image into memory.

One of the copies would be used to display a preview to the user, the other would be used to apply the edits made.

Once the user is happy with their edits, offer to save the new image from memory to disk.